# Where is Nanda Parbat meant to be?

Tags: dc, arrow, arrowverse

Many significant events in the TV series Arrow have taken place in Nanda Parbat, the home of the League of Assassins. My question is, according to the DC comics, where is Nanda Parbat meant to be located, and is that contradicted by anything from the TV series, given how quickly Team Arrow and others seem to be able to travel there?

Comment: Is there really a need for a Nanda Parbat tag..?

Comment: I have found several assertions that Nanda Parbat is in the mountains of Tibet; however, these are not sourced, and I don't have ready access to the source material.

Comment: @DangerZone Since it bothered you enough to want to comment on it, I deleted it.

Comment: I feel like I vaguely remember Malcolm Merlyn or someone mentioning the location of Nanda Parbat. Hopefully someone jumps in with a screenshot, script reference, or YouTube clip with the location rather than vague, confilcting Wiki entries.

Answer (score 9):

According to most recent DC comics, it's located somewhere in the Himalayan mountains:

[image: Nanda Parbat location]

Answer (score 6):

Pulled from Wikipedia:

> Patterned after the fictional Shangri-La and the real Nanga Parbat in
>   Pakistan. Nanda Parbat is a hidden city nestled high in the mountains
>   of Tibet; it is said to be a place of healing and enlightenment

From the Arrow Wiki:

> Nanda Parbat is a city hidden beneath the Hindu Kush mountain range.

Also from the Arrow Wiki:

> The Hindu Kush is a mountain range in Pakistan Asia. It is home to the
>   hidden city Nanda Parbat.

So there is some division among sources. I always heard it was in Tibet. That's at least where the League of Shadows operated from in Batman Begins.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is not the first time that Arrow, and DC Comics, have created fictional locations based on real ones. Corto Maltese, which shared its name with a Season 3 episode, is an entirely fictional country in South America.

Answer (score 0):

I actually descend from an area near the Himalayan mountain range. I can tell you the area seems to be culturally ambiguous since it's a mountainous range. It doesn't really belong to any of the neighboring cultures, India, Pakistan, China, Tibet and so on. The surrounding cultures all travel through the area though, and leave their influence so it's not far fetched that a secretive group operating out of there has the combined martial traditions of Arab Assassins, Indian Thugs and Chinese Ninjas, and are multilingual among these cultures.

Comment: Thank you for your post, it provides interesting and useful information. However, I suggest that you edit your answer to specifically address the original question which was "according to the DC comics, where is Nanda Parbat meant to be located, and is that contradicted by anything from the TV series, given how quickly Team Arrow and others seem to be able to travel there?"

Comment: very true. Well according to DC it's in the himilaya region which is where the real nanga parbat is anyways. They would have to be using Jets provided by Argus to be travelling so fast to and from there. 

I see where this question is coming from. They go more into detail to their ventures between Lian Yu and Star City then they do with Nanda Parbat.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the location was based upon the real live Nanga Parbat, a mountain in the Astore region of Pakistan, which is in the Himalayas.

The original Nanda Parbat also had nothing to do with the League of Assassins/Shadows. Rather, it was the sanctuary of Rama Kushna, the entity who empowered Boston Brand as Deadman. It was a place where people sought refuge and respite from spiritual foes (see Richard Dragon's time at Namda Parbat, for example).

I think it's connection to the League of Assassins is mostly from Batman Begins.

Comment: Sooources, we need some sooources *vocalizes*